# Is there a way to block exectution until asynchronuous function is completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, promise

I have an asynchronous function that is called from a synchronous function as shown below.

```js
public syncFunction(data: Data): Value[] {
    const results: Value[] = [];
    // read data object and do some stuff
    results.push(data.value)
    // Call async function
    const val = this.asyncFunction()
    results.push(val);
    return results;
  }
public async asyncFunction(): Value {
    let result = await this.anotherAsyncFunction();
    // Do some stuff
    return result;
  }
```

By doing this, the type of the variable named `val` it is, of course, a Promise.
What I would like to do is resolve the promise, push the value in the `results`array and than return the array.
I tried to use `this.asyncFunction.then()` but the return statements is executed first.
Is it possible to do something like this?
Within the project all functions are synchronous and I do not have the possibility to modify it

Comment: What you need to check is this -  https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: *"Is it possible to do something like this?"* I'm afraid not, no. You can't return the result of an asynchronous operation from a synchronous function, by their very nature. The asynchronous result isn't available when the synchronous function exits.

Comment: @Sh.Pavel - It's clear that the OP knows how to use `async`/`await`.